# How to rework rolling sum using Numpy.strides?

Tags: python, numpy

I have this code that works. I was wondering how to implement using
np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided  or avoid loops.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Fetch Apple stock data
apple_data = yf.download('AAPL', start='2024-01-01', end='2024-03-31')

# Extract volume data
apple_volume = apple_data['Volume']

# Resample to ensure every date is included
apple_volume = apple_volume.resample('D').ffill()

# Function to calculate rolling sum with reset using NumPy
def rolling_sum_with_reset(series, window_size):
    rolling_sums = np.zeros(len(series))
    current_sum = 0
    for i, value in enumerate(series):
        if i % window_size == 0:
            current_sum = 0
        current_sum += value
        rolling_sums[i] = current_sum
    return rolling_sums


rolling_3_day_volume = rolling_sum_with_reset(apple_volume, 3)
```

Comment: Can you use numpy functions like cumsum, reshape, and repeat ? (ps: I didn't downvote, It's just my que )

Comment: cumsum wont reset the value to zero. so still looping

Comment: What you want is unfortunately not possible. Resetting is not vectorizable.

Comment: Are you okay using `accumulate` from `itertools` ie `np.emath.nx.itertools.accumulate`??

Comment: Or even `pandas.groupby` function

Comment: With numpy functions, I could only find `np.add.reduceat` which instead of cumsum does the sum. Wish there was `np.add.accumulateat` but well thats not there. So perhaps you will have to settle for `itertools.accumulate` which would take in the condition as needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For a sample array of integers:

In [225]: arr = np.arange(90); x=rolling_sum_with_reset(arr,3)
In [226]: x
Out[226]: 
array([  0.,   1.,   3.,   3.,   7.,  12.,   6.,  13.,  21.,   9.,  19.,
        30.,  12.,  25.,  39.,  15.,  31.,  48.,  18.,  37.,  57.,  21.,
        43.,  66.,  24.,  49.,  75.,  27.,  55.,  84.,  30.,  61.,  93.,
        33.,  67., 102.,  36.,  73., 111.,  39.,  79., 120.,  42.,  85.,
       129.,  45.,  91., 138.,  48.,  97., 147.,  51., 103., 156.,  54.,
       109., 165.,  57., 115., 174.,  60., 121., 183.,  63., 127., 192.,
        66., 133., 201.,  69., 139., 210.,  72., 145., 219.,  75., 151.,
       228.,  78., 157., 237.,  81., 163., 246.,  84., 169., 255.,  87.,
       175., 264.])
```

If the `arr` has a multiple of `windows` size, it can be reshaped to a 2d array, and cumsum applied to each row:

```
In [227]: y = np.cumsum(arr.reshape(-1,3), axis=1).ravel()
```

That matches your result:

```
In [228]: np.allclose(x,y)
Out[228]: True
```

I think `cumsum` can be used with some sort of 'reset' step array, but this reshape approach is so much easier.

`as_strided` can be used to create the windows, but since you don't need overlap in the windows, the result is the same as this `reshape`:

```
In [230]: np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(arr,3)[::3]
Out[230]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17],
        ...
```

### for size 10 window

```
In [237]: rolling_sum_with_reset(arr,10)
Out[237]: 
array([  0.,   1.,   3.,   6.,  10.,  15.,  21.,  28.,  36.,  45.,  10.,
        21.,  33.,  46.,  60.,  75.,  91., 108., 126., 145.,  20.,  41.,
        63.,  86., 110., 135., 161., 188., 216., 245.,  30.,  61.,  93.,
       126., 160., 195., 231., 268., 306., 345.,  40.,  81., 123., 166.,
       210., 255., 301., 348., 396., 445.,  50., 101., 153., 206., 260.,
       315., 371., 428., 486., 545.,  60., 121., 183., 246., 310., 375.,
       441., 508., 576., 645.,  70., 141., 213., 286., 360., 435., 511.,
       588., 666., 745.,  80., 161., 243., 326., 410., 495., 581., 668.,
       756., 845.])

In [238]: y = np.cumsum(arr.reshape(-1,10), axis=1).ravel()

In [239]: y
Out[239]: 
array([  0,   1,   3,   6,  10,  15,  21,  28,  36,  45,  10,  21,  33,
        46,  60,  75,  91, 108, 126, 145,  20,  41,  63,  86, 110, 135,
       161, 188, 216, 245,  30,  61,  93, 126, 160, 195, 231, 268, 306,
       345,  40,  81, 123, 166, 210, 255, 301, 348, 396, 445,  50, 101,
       153, 206, 260, 315, 371, 428, 486, 545,  60, 121, 183, 246, 310,
       375, 441, 508, 576, 645,  70, 141, 213, 286, 360, 435, 511, 588,
       666, 745,  80, 161, 243, 326, 410, 495, 581, 668, 756, 845])
```

Comment: There might be some adjustment needed (with `np.pad` ?) if the `arr` couldn't be reshaped (e.g. window size 3, number of days 31)

Comment: yup works, thanks

Comment: worked yesterday not today.   I think I need to pad the end of array to multiples of window. (3,10 etc)  like  >>  np.arange(91);

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using [numba](/questions/tagged/numba) to speed up the computation:

```py
import numba


@numba.njit
def rolling_sum_with_reset_numba(series, window_size):
    rolling_sums = np.empty_like(series)
    current_sum = 0
    for i, value in enumerate(series):
        if i % window_size == 0:
            current_sum = 0
        current_sum += value
        rolling_sums[i] = current_sum
    return rolling_sums
```

---

Full example:

```py
import numba
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from itertools import accumulate

# generate some sample data:
np.random.seed(42)
dr = pd.date_range("2024-01-01", "2024-03-3", freq="1D")

apple_data = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Date": dr, "Volume": np.random.randint(1000, 10_000, size=len(dr))}
).set_index("Date")

# Extract volume data
apple_volume = apple_data["Volume"]


# Function to calculate rolling sum with reset using NumPy
def rolling_sum_with_reset(series, window_size):
    rolling_sums = np.zeros(len(series))
    current_sum = 0
    for i, value in enumerate(series):
        if i % window_size == 0:
            current_sum = 0
        current_sum += value
        rolling_sums[i] = current_sum
    return rolling_sums


@numba.njit
def rolling_sum_with_reset_numba(series, window_size):
    rolling_sums = np.empty_like(series)
    current_sum = 0
    for i, value in enumerate(series):
        if i % window_size == 0:
            current_sum = 0
        current_sum += value
        rolling_sums[i] = current_sum
    return rolling_sums

def rolling_sum_with_reset_accumulate(series, window_size):
    rv = accumulate(
        enumerate(series), lambda x, y: x * (y[0] % 3 > 0) + y[1], initial=0
    )
    next(rv)
    return list(rv)

rolling_3_day_volume = rolling_sum_with_reset(apple_volume, 3)
rolling_3_day_volume_nb = rolling_sum_with_reset_numba(apple_volume.values, 3)

print(rolling_3_day_volume)
print(rolling_3_day_volume_nb)
```

Prints:

```
[ 8270. 10130. 16520.  6191. 12925. 20190.  1466.  6892. 13470.  9322.
 12007. 13776.  7949. 11382. 17693.  6051. 13471. 15655.  5555.  9940.
 17336.  9666. 13224. 22073.  3047.  6794.  7983.  3734.  7739. 13397.
  2899. 11633. 13900.  2528.  7084. 11974.  9838. 16231. 26023.  9433.
 17946. 21558.  8041. 15276. 21762.  8099.  9874. 19100.  4152.  6737.
 11680.  8555. 12628. 14649.  4843. 13832. 21705.  6675.  7836. 13133.
  1995. 10624. 12640.]

[ 8270 10130 16520  6191 12925 20190  1466  6892 13470  9322 12007 13776
  7949 11382 17693  6051 13471 15655  5555  9940 17336  9666 13224 22073
  3047  6794  7983  3734  7739 13397  2899 11633 13900  2528  7084 11974
  9838 16231 26023  9433 17946 21558  8041 15276 21762  8099  9874 19100
  4152  6737 11680  8555 12628 14649  4843 13832 21705  6675  7836 13133
  1995 10624 12640]
```

---

Benchmark with `perfplot`:

```py
import perfplot


def generate_df(n):
    dr = pd.date_range(
        pd.to_datetime("2024-01-01") - pd.Timedelta(f"{30*n} days"),
        "2024-01-01",
        freq="1D",
    )

    return pd.DataFrame(
        {"Date": dr, "Volume": np.random.randint(1000, 10_000, size=len(dr))}
    ).set_index("Date")


perfplot.show(
    setup=generate_df,
    kernels=[
        lambda df: rolling_sum_with_reset(df["Volume"], 3),
        lambda df: rolling_sum_with_reset_numba(df["Volume"].values, 3),
        lambda df: rolling_sum_with_reset_accumulate(df["Volume"], 3),
    ],
    labels=["original", "numba", "accumulate"],
    n_range=[1, 2, 6, 12, 24, 48, 120, 240],  # number of months
    xlabel="N",
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
    equality_check=np.allclose,
)
```

Creates this graph on my machine (AMD 5700x/Ubuntu 20.04/Python 3.11):

```
pd.__version__='2.2.1'
np.__version__='1.26.4'
numba.__version__='0.59.0'
```

[image]

Comment: Neat. Can you measure numpy.strides too? Also, please state your versions of python, numpy, pandas, numba

Comment: Can you measure against itertools? ie `accumulate(enumerate(a), lambda x,y: x*(y[0] % 3 > 0) + y[1], initial = 0)` of course this has a value at the beginning which need to be removed

Comment: @Onyambu I've added the version with `itertools.accumulate`

Comment: @smci I've updated the answer with versions, but wait for edit to hpaul's answer (current version errors if the window size isn't corresponding with number of days - reshape error)

Comment: will this work for 3, 10, 20 days ... right now debugging with the my sample  above. Your code runs, just transferring into real code base is question...

Comment: as a sanity check can you please use the yfinance data.. there is some  wrong.  >>> This error may have been caused by the following argument(s):
- argument 0: Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: @Merlin The `yfinance` throws `['AAPL']: Exception('%ticker%: No timezone found, symbol may be delisted')` error for me. But the numba version should work (just make sure you put numpy array as parameter - hence `df["Volume"].values`)

Comment: AAPL is not delisted. weird |     new error <source missing, REPL/exec in use?>   running code in notebook --- never used numba before,

Answer (score 1):

Can we do it like:

```
def rolling_sum_with_reset(series, window_size):
    shape = series.shape[:-1] + (series.shape[-1] - window_size + 1, window_size)
    strides = series.strides + (series.strides[-1],)
    rolling_strides = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(series, shape=shape, strides=strides)
    rolling_sums = np.sum(rolling_strides, axis=1)
    return rolling_sums.flatten()
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strides'

Comment: Merlin, convert the Series to a numpy array!

Comment: @hpaulj  -- long time  since seeing you--  did that results aren't comparable.

Comment: @Nerlin, this function does run with an array, such as in my answer, because an array has a `strides` attribute.  A pandas Series does not.  But, yes, I agree that the result is different from what your (or my) function does.